# Javascript to hide html form by browser detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser

my question is how to hide some html element based on what browser users is using. For the browser detection part, I have completed.
Those isChrome stuff returns "true" or "false" to be used in the later if condition.
What code am I missing to connect the js if/else section to css to hide the login field.Or any other better way to do this?Thanks.

```js
  // Firefox 1.0+
    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    
    // Chrome 1+
    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
    
    // Edge 20+
    var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
    
     // Internet Explorer 6-11
    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
    
        
var output = 'Detecting browsers:<hr>';
output += 'isFirefox: ' + isFirefox + '<br>';
output += 'isChrome: ' + isChrome + '<br>';
output += 'isEdge: ' + isEdge + '<br><br>';

document.getElementById("browser").innerHTML = output;

//if ( isChrome==true){
// $(".LoginField").css("visibility","hidden");
//}
```

```css
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.not-visible {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.LoginField{
  visibility: visible; 
}
```

```html
<p class="visible">The first paragraph is visible.</p>
<p class="not-visible">The second paragraph is NOT visible.</p>

<div id="browser"></div>
<div class="LoginField">login fields</div>
```

Comment: What you're probably missing is the  $( document ).ready(function() { }) which you should wrap your  if statement in.

Comment: @LeoFarmer Why?By adding `$( document ).ready(function() { })`,this function trace id and class globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works exactly as expected, provided you have remembered to include jQuery on the page. Having said that, you can simply check `if (isChrome)` - you don't need to check that it's equal to `true`. You also don't need the CSS to state that `.LoginField` is visible by default.

Here's a working example, where the login credentials are visible on every browser but Chrome:

```js
// Firefox 1.0+
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

// Chrome 1+
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;

// Edge 20+
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

// Internet Explorer 6-11
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/ false || !!document.documentMode;


var output = 'Detecting browsers:<hr>';
output += 'isFirefox: ' + isFirefox + '<br>';
output += 'isChrome: ' + isChrome + '<br>';
output += 'isEdge: ' + isEdge + '<br><br>';

document.getElementById("browser").innerHTML = output;

if (isChrome) {
  $(".LoginField").css("visibility", "hidden");
}
```

```css
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.not-visible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="visible">The first paragraph is visible.</p>
<p class="not-visible">The second paragraph is NOT visible.</p>

<div id="browser"></div>
<div class="LoginField">login fields</div>
```